# What is the "envelope" of the magnetic field, in NMR?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, terminology, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Let $B_1$ be RF pulse.
According to the following lecture,  $B_1^e$ represents the "envelope" of $B_1$ and under the labo-frame coordination, following be satisfied;

$B_1\left(t\right)=B_1^e\left(t\right)\exp{\left(-j\left(\omega_0t-\theta\right)\right)}$

https://www.coursera.org/learn/mri-fundamentals/home/week/2

### My question:

> - What does the "envelope" mean ?
> - $B_1$  may be a vector field,  represents magnetic component of RF pulse , am I right ?
> - $B_1^e (t) := \exp(j (\omega_0t -θ)) B_1 (t)$ , am I right?
> - Does this take a value in real numbers?

[image]

Link,

- [How is a 180° RF pulse in NMR?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/758840/)
- [What is 90 or 180 "degree" RF pulse in MRI?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756984/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(your equations are missing the $t$ variable)

Any signal $r(t)$ can be written as $r(t) = A(t)cos(\omega_0 t) + B(t)sin(\omega_0 t)$ for a given $\omega_0$ but if the frequency content, i.e., spectral width of $r(t)$ is much less than $\omega_0$ that means that the bandwdiths of $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are also much less than that, and if $\omega_0$ is selected *properly* then they can be confined near the base band. In that case we can call $\omega_0$ the carrier frequency and the $z(t)=A(t)-\mathfrak j B(t)$ is called the complex (baseband) envelope of $r(t) =\Re {[z(t)e^{\mathfrak j \omega_0 t }]}$.

Since most RF filters and circuits are narrow band relative to their "center" frequency, their impulse response can be represented with an equivalent complex envelope. This is usually very convenient because then these complex envelopes of the linear circuits act directly on the signal's complex envelope *independently* of the carrier frequency.

To calculate the *real* signal just take the $\Re$ part of the complex time function including its carrier exponential. The real part of the *complex envelope* is not meaningful by itself. This is reflected in the usual *physical* arbitrariness of the phase shift $\theta$ in the complex exponential. That $\theta$ is just a reference time shift but as it changes it "rotates" the complex envelope. The relationship between the real and imaginary parts, however, is not arbitrary, they are related through a [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), see also [analytic signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal).

Answer (score 1):

> What does the "envelope" mean ?

When you produce a RF pulse you start with the envelope. The envelope is the part that you design. For small flip angles it is the Fourier transform of the slice profile. For large flip angles you solve the Bloch equations in the rotating reference frame.

Once you have the envelope you obtain the final RF pulse by modulating the envelope by the Larmor frequency. This is what your equation says.

> B1 may be a vector field, represents magnetic component of RF pulse , am I right ?

Yes.

> $B_1^e (t) := \exp(j (\omega_0 -θ)) B_1 (t)$ , am I right?

Yes. This is called demodulation.

> Does this take a value in real numbers?

No, it is complex valued. The real component is fed into one port of the quadrature coil and the imaginary component is fed into the other port.